# Share dynamic tables between Flink programs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a Flink job that creates a Dynamic table from a database changelog stream. The table definition looks as follows:

```scala
tableEnv.sqlUpdate("""
      CREATE TABLE some_table_name (
          id INTEGER,
          name STRING,
          created_at BIGINT,
          updated_at BIGINT
      )
      WITH (
          'connector' = 'kafka',
          'topic' = 'topic',
          'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
          'properties.zookeeper.connect' = 'localhost:2181',
          'properties.group.id' = 'group_1',
          'format' = 'debezium-json',
          'debezium-json.schema-include' = 'true'
      )
    """)
```

When trying to reference that table in another running Flink application on the same cluster,  my program returns an error: `SqlValidatorException: Object 'some_table_name' not found`. Is it possible to register that table somehow such that other programs can use it? For example in a statement like this:

```scala
  tableEnv.sqlQuery("""
    SELECT count(*) FROM some_table_name
  """).execute().print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a *table* in Flink doesn't hold any data. Another Flink application can independently create another table backed by the same Kafka topic, for example . So not sharing tables between applications isn't as tragic as you might expect.

But you can share tables by storing them in an external *catalog*. E.g., you could use an Apache Hive catalog for this purpose. See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/catalogs/) for more info.